# Calculus trig derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I evaluate the following two derivatives.

$g(t)=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(t)$

For this derivative I know $\sin^2+\cos^2(t)=1$

so there derivative of $1$ is $0$

For my second question I have to find the second derivative of $h(t)=\sec(3t)$ at $t=\pi$

I found the first derivative as $3\sec(3t)\tan(3t)$

The second derivative I got

$3[\sec(3t)(3\sec^2(3t))+\tan(3t)(3)\sec(3t)\tan(3t)]$

But how would I apply the $\pi$ to the $t$

Comment: Note that $\sin(3\pi)=\sin(\pi)=0$, and $\cos(3\pi)=\cos(\pi)=-1$. Now the other trig functions are easy. Conveniently, $\tan$ dies.

Comment: Where does the red one close in: $$3[\sec(3t)\color{red}{(}3\sec^2(3t)+\tan(3t)(3)\sec(3t)\tan(3t)]?$$

Comment: Oh sorry at the end of 3t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to substitute $\pi$ for $t$ in our expression for the derivative.

So we will need $\tan(3\pi)$ and $\sec(3\pi)$.  One is more likely to be comfortable with $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Note that $\sin(3\pi)=\sin(\pi)=0$, and $\cos(3\pi)=\cos(\pi)=-1$. Now the other trig functions are easy. Conveniently, $\tan$ dies at $3\pi$. You should end up with $-9$.

Comment: yes I have gotten -9 too.

Comment: because $3sec^2(3pi)$ is 3

Comment: Yes, basically because $\cos(3\pi)$, and therefore $\sec(3\pi)$, is $-1$.